# Create a field that sums up all the time an entry has occurred prior to a certain row

Tags: pandas, counting

I have a DataFrame that contains several people who submitted projects. People's names occur several times in the DF. One column contains the information about the year each person launched a project: I'd like to create a new column called "previous projects" that contains, at any point in time, the number of project a person has previously submitted.
Here's an overview of the DF (I've already sorted it based on Year): [df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icNCp.png).

I tried to run the following code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Cartel3.xlsx')
df1 = df.sort_values(by=['Year'], ascending=True)
df1
creatorlist = []
df1['previous_projects']=""
for row in df1.itertuples():
    creatorlist.append(row.Creator)
    if creatorlist.count(row.Creator) > 0:
        df1['previous_projects']= creatorlist.count(row.Creator)
df1
```

The issue, I think, is that with the for-loop all the names are automatically added to the list, so when I run list.count(), I get the overall number of occurrences of a name regardless of its timing.

Hope all is clear,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Mayby `df1['prev_project'] = df1.groupby('Creator').cumcount()`. You should include your data as text, not pictures.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You solved my issue! I'm new to Stack so sorry if I didn't upload the image properly. Thank you very much!